# TeXstudio error: File `beamer.cls' not found. \usepackage

Tags: beamer

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, my editor is texstudio. Last week I reinstalled my texlive because I have been some problems.I removed completely  the texlive and reinstall it. Some days ago I made some presentation on the beamer without troubles.

Today I opened a beamer presentation and I had the follow message:

> File 'beamer. cls' not found. \usepackage

This problem, it's only on Beamer. Using another \documentclass the texlive compile normally.I removed Texlive completely and installed again and this problem yet continues.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you edit your whole log into your question, starting from the first line and going until at least the line where you get the error?

Comment: What exactly did you install? Ubuntus TeXLive? If Ubuntus TeXLive which parts of if? TeXLive in Ubuntu is split up into many Ubuntu packages and it gets very confusing which Ubuntu package provides which LaTeX package. The `apt-file` utility can help.

Comment: First I installed by apt install texlive-full... the problem not solved. After that I downloaded the texlive iso from ctan (http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/systems/texlive/Images/) like I did in previous versions and reinstalled.